# How to pass a GeoPosition from one class to another?

Tags: c#, navigation

I'm trying to pass a GeoPosition variable named `MyGeoPosition` via the navigation service but I think I'm getting one of the steps wrong somewhere as when I pull the data from the OnNavigatedTo method of the other class it gives `geopositon doesn't exist in the current context`

In class number one I pass the variable like this:

```
private async void setLocationBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            await this.GetCoordinates();
            //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Maps.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Maps.xaml?GeoX={0}&GeoY={1}", MyGeoPosition), UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Method for getting the location:

```
    private async Task GetCoordinates(string name = "My Car")
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // Get the phone's current location.
            Geolocator MyGeolocator = new Geolocator();
            MyGeolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 5;
            Geoposition MyGeoPosition = null;

            try
            {
                MyGeoPosition = await MyGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Location is disabled in phone settings or capabilities are not checked.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Something else happened while acquiring the location.
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        });
    }
```

Class number two where I'm trying to retrieve the variable data:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("MyGeoPosition"))
            {
              var MyGeoPosition = new GeoCoordinate(geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude, geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude); 
            }


            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't have Phone SDK installed but will give it a try. 
Looks like you have get it wrong with the naviagtion parameter. Give the latitude and longtitude as parameter like shown in my sketch and then recover your location out of the parameter. the key have to match the paramter in your navigation uri.

class number one:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Maps.xaml?GeoLat={0}&GeoLong={1}", MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Latitude,MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Longitude), UriKind.Relative));
```

class number two:

```
   if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("GeoLat") && NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("GeoLong"))
            {
              var latitude = NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLat"];
              var longtitude = NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLong"];
              var MyGeoPosition = new GeoCoordinate(latitude , longtitude ); 
            }
```

You may have to fix some little errors, I typed it without VS.

See: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation
 and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate

Much better way to get the value is 
TryGetValue()

```
string latitude;
    if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue(“GeoLat”,out latitude))
```

like they **show here:**

developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_pass_strings_between_pages_on_Windows_Phone

Comment: I tried the above solution but at the statement `var MyGeoPosition = new GeoCoordinate(latitude , longtitude ); ` but it gives an error stating that GeoCordinate take (double,double) parameters..do I have to parse to double? Could you show how to do this in your answer?

Comment: Please Try `Double.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLat"])` 

But take care it is unsafe - look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Double_methods(v=vs.110).aspx and take `TryParse(String, Double)`.